# Django template check if current time falls between start and end times

Tags: python, django

I have 2 fields in my model named **Restaurant** as follows:

```
start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True)
end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True)
```

I have a view in which i am filtering my model to give a list to my template as follows:

```
restaurants = Restaurant.objects.filter(location__icontains = location)
return render_to_response('restaurant.html', { 'user': request.user, 'restaurant': restaurants }, RequestContext(request))
```

and in my template i have:

```
{% if restaurant %}
    <ul class="list-group">
        {% for r in restaurant %}
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <h5>
                    <legend>{{ r.restaurant_name|capfirst }}</legend>
                    <a href="/order/#/showmenu/{{ r.id }}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">View Menu</a>
                </h5>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

I am trying to look if there is a template tag that can be useful to check if the *current time* falls between my `start_time` and `end_time`, then show the `View Menu` button, else not show.

i have gone through the documentation if i could find one but maybe i missed it. Any help will be appreciated.

Try 1:

```
>>> s = Restaurant.objects.all()
>>> s[0].is_open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/xxx/myapp/models.py", line 64, in is_open
    return self.start_time <= datetime.datetime.now().time < self.end_time
TypeError: can't compare datetime.time to builtin_function_or_method
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't something you'd do with a template tag. One option would be to provide a method on the Restaurant model:

```
def is_open(self):
    return self.start_time <= datetime.datetime.now().time() < self.end_time
```

and check `{% if restaurant.is_open %}` in the template.

Alternatively, you could change the query so that it only returns restaurants that are open:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
restaurants = Restaurant.objects.filter(
    location__icontains=location,
    start_time__lte=now,
    end_time__gte=now
)
```

Comment: this is fantastic. Thank you :)

Comment: This is the best answer :)

Comment: @Daniel:  i tried this in the terminal  >>> s = Restaurant.objects.all()
>>> s[0].is_open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/abhishek.yeruva/workspace/myreps/bhojanam/bhojanamapp/models.py", line 64, in is_open
    return self.start_time <= datetime.datetime.now().time < self.end_time
TypeError: can't compare datetime.time to builtin_function_or_method

Comment: Sorry, it should be `datetime.datetime.now().time()`, answer updated.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use a template tag, since this is part of your business logic.
Instead consider, for example, adding a property to your model:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):

    @property
    def is_open(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
        return self.start_time() <= now <= self.end_time()
```

This way, you have defined a solid business rule on model level and are able to use it in the template:

```
{% if r.is_open %}
    <a>your link</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: hi for some reason it is always returning me a false

Comment: i mean i tried all the 3 solutions above. I thought i have an issue with my times entries but they look fine too

Comment: Okay let me try it locally and I'll update if I find an issue

Comment: ok i tried this in the terminal: >>> s = Restaurant.objects.all()
>>> s[0].is_open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/abhishek.yeruva/workspace/myreps/bhojanam/bhojanamapp/models.py", line 64, in is_open
    return self.start_time <= datetime.datetime.now().time < self.end_time
TypeError: can't compare datetime.time to builtin_function_or_method

Comment: Yes, I tested it locally. Updating

Answer (score 2):

I think the template tag you are trying to look for does not exist. But the good news is that you can create your own method or property for your Restaurant model instances.

Just create a method in the Restaurant model, which should do the following:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True)

    def is_open_now(self):
        return self.start_time <= datetime.datetime.now() < self.end_time
```

Then, on your templates:

```
{% if restaurant %}
    <ul class="list-group">
        {% for r in restaurant %}
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <h5>
                    <legend>{{ r.restaurant_name|capfirst }}</legend>
                    {% if r.restaurant.is_open_now %}
                        <a href="/order/#/showmenu/{{ r.id }}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">View Menu</a>
                    {% endif %}
                </h5>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Name copied and method has a bug :P

Comment: It should be `start_time < now < end_time`. It doesn't matter if it's `>` or `>=` (that is for the OP to decide), but `start_time < now < start_time` will never be true :P

Comment: Thank you very much @Alvaro, fixed that!!